# Why does bootstrap modal activation work after page refresh but not after initial form push?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal

I am pushing a form to our users. The form has a button that is intended to open a bootstrap multi-step-modal. When I push the form this button does not open the modal, but if I refresh the page, then it works as intended.

I have tried having the button manually open the modal with jquery, but that breaks other functionality of the modal.

Here is the definition of the button and the modal.

```
<input  type="button"  class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="false" data-target="#demo-modal-3" value ="Create"/>
<div class="modal multi-step" style="color:black;" id="demo-modal-3">
```

I am performing a minimum of additional javascript beyond the default behavior.

```
$.getScript("/files/bootstrap.min.js", function() {
    $.getScript("/files/multi-step-modal.js", function() {
    sendEvent = function(sel, step) {
        $(sel).trigger('next.m.' + step);
    }

    $('#demo-modal-3').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {

        //reset();
        console.log('modal reset');
        $('#demo-modal-3').trigger('next.m.1');

        $('#demo-modal-3').find('.step-1').show();
    });
});
});
```

When the button functions properly, I can see the div is modified to display the modal.

```
<div class="modal multi-step in" style="color: black; display: block;" id="demo-modal-3">
```

However when it is not working, the div is also modified, but display is set to 'none' and the modal does not appear.

```
<div class="modal multi-step" style="color: black; display: none;" id="demo-modal-3">
```